# Topics arent being added

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Im pretty new to both python and django , currently reading the Python Crash Course by Eric Matthes . Im trying to code a simple learning log , but im having some issues adding new topics using the django form . Heres the code:

**urls.py:**
from django.urls import path , re_path
from . import views

```
urlpatterns = [
    #Home page
    
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('topics/', views.topics , name='topics'),
    re_path(r'^topics/(?P<topic_id>\d+)/$' , views.topic , name = 'topic'),
    re_path(r'^new_topic/$' , views.new_topic , name = 'new_topic')
]

app_name = 'learning_logs'
```

**part of view.py:**

```
def new_topic(request):
    if request.method != 'POST':
        form = TopicForm
    else:
        form = TopicForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('learning_logs:topics'))

    context = {'form' : form}
    return render(request , 'learning_logs/new_topic.html' , context)
```

**new_topic.html:**
{% extends 'learning_logs/base.html' %}

```
{% block content %}

<p>Added a new topic:</p>
<form action="{% url 'learning_logs:new_topic' %}" method="post">

{% csrf_token %}
{{form.as_p}}
<button name='submit'>add topic</button>

</form>

{% endblock content %}
```

**topics.html:**
{% extends 'learning_logs/base.html' %}

```
{% block content %}

<p>Topics</p>

<ul>

  {% for topic in topics %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'learning_logs:topic' topic.id %}">{{topic}}</a></li>
  {% empty %}
    <li>No topics have been added yet.</li>
  {% endfor %}

</ul>

<a href="{% url 'learning_logs:new_topic' %}">Add a new topic:</a>

{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: It might be because of you not running form.save. Try add (): `form.save()`

Comment: that was it. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the brackets are missing. It should form.save() as bkrop mentioned